# Highlight pressed(selected) date in React Native Calendars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, highlight

In the project that I have, I used react-native-calendars library. Currently, I am able to get date by onPress. But the question is how to highlight that date. Logic: when the user presses the date it should be highlighted in whatever colour. The major reason is to distinguish the selected date from the rest of the dates. This is source [code](https://snack.expo.io/H12PVcmJL)

This is a snippet of my code where which is responsible for getting the current date:

```
state={
  selectedDate: '',
}

const getSelectedDayEvents = (date) => {
    let serviceDate = moment(date);
    serviceDate = serviceDate.format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    this.setState({selectedDate: serviceDate});
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to the document](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#date-marking) you need to use `markedDates={}` to display highlighted days.

```
<Calendar
  markedDates={{
    '2012-05-16': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-05-17': {marked: true},
    '2012-05-18': {marked: true, dotColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0},
    '2012-05-19': {disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true}
  }}
/>
```

**Edit**

1. Add`markedDates` to the initial state.

```
state = {
    selectedDate: "",
    markedDates: {}
};
```

2. Change `getSelectedDayEvents` function to create `markedDates` object & assign that to state.

```
getSelectedDayEvents = date => {
    let markedDates = {};
    markedDates[date] = { selected: true, color: '#00B0BF', textColor: '#FFFFFF' };
    let serviceDate = moment(date);
    serviceDate = serviceDate.format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    this.setState({
        selectedDate: serviceDate,
        markedDates: markedDates
    });
};
```

3. Change Calendar component to accept `markedDates`

```
<Calendar
  style={{ height: 300, width: "90%", justifyContent: "center" }}
  theme={{
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    calendarBackground: "#ffffff",
    todayTextColor: "#57B9BB",
    dayTextColor: "#222222",
    textDisabledColor: "#d9e1e8",
    monthTextColor: "#57B9BB",
    arrowColor: "#57B9BB",
    textDayFontWeight: "300",
    textMonthFontWeight: "bold",
    textDayHeaderFontWeight: "500",
    textDayFontSize: 16,
    textMonthFontSize: 18,
    selectedDayBackgroundColor: "#57B9BB",
    selectedDayTextColor: "white",
    textDayHeaderFontSize: 8
  }}
  minDate={"1996-05-10"}
  maxDate={"2030-05-30"}
  monthFormat={"MMMM yyyy "}
  markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
  scrollEnabled={true}
  horizontal={true}
  showScrollIndicator={true}
  disableMonthChange={true}
  onDayPress={day => {
    getSelectedDayEvents(day.dateString);
  }}
/>
```

If you have any dough feel free to ask. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: yeah, I got it from documentation, the question is how to implement dynamic color change ? https://snack.expo.io/Syxvr4klU check it out, I have done it, but it is static

Comment: @JasurKurbanov I changed my answer according to your requirement check that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Calendar
minDate={this.state.date}
onDayPress={(day) =>  this.setState({selected_date: day.dateString})}
renderArrow={(direction) =>  direction == 'left' ? <IconContainer iconObject={LEFT_ICON}  /> : <IconContainer iconObject={RIGHT_ICON}  />}
markedDates={{
  [this.state.selected_date]: {
    selected: true,
    disableTouchEvent: true,
    selectedColor: '#F1EFFE',
    selectedTextColor: '#7954FA',
  },
}}
theme={{
  todayTextColor: '#7954FA',
'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
  dayHeader:{
    color:'#616061',
    fontWeight:'bold'
  }
}
}}
/>
```

state: --

```
state={
    date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    selected_date:null,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    const [date,setDate]=useState<any>()
    
    <Calendar
         markedDates={{
          [date]: {selected: true,selectedColor:'red',
          disableTouchEvent: true,
          selectedTextColor: 'orange'
        },
          
              }}
          onDayPress={day => {
            console.log('selected day', day);
            setDate(day.dateString)
          }}
/>
```